# Using IDisposable with file download action in C# .NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I found a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3084366/how-do-i-dispose-my-filestream-when-implementing-a-file-download-in-asp-net/44370892#44370892) about using disposable object with the download action. However I found the file I created was disposed before the download action therefore it returned "Could not find file..." error. Any idea? Thanks you.

below is my code

```
public FileResult DownloadPDF(int id)
{
    var downloadFileName = id.ToString() + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss")+".pdf";
    // TemporaryFileHelper implements the Idisposable
    using(TemporaryFileHelper tempDownloadFile = new TemporaryFileHelper())
    {
        //obtain temp file name and path 
        var tempFileNameAndPath = tempDownloadFile.GetTempFileNameWithPath();
        //generate temp file with above file name and path
        _pdfReportServices.GenerateTempPdfForDownload(id, tempFileNameAndPath);
        //return file result
        return File(tempFileNameAndPath, "application/pdf", Server.UrlEncode(downloadFileName));
    }

}
```

Comment: Dipose is used to remove unmanaged resources after using it. So call your Dispose method after downloading your file.

Comment: No, do not close it. The File() method returns a FileResult , see the linked duplicates.

Comment: Another [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42238826)

Comment: Thanks for answering,however the file is saved as a temp file in app folder .I only pass a string of file path, but a filestream to File(). How did the file get disposed before the return?